# JQuery animating font-size not animating

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to animate the font-size of a div, reducing it to 0px.
Here's my attempt:
http://jsfiddle.net/corington/15gw9Lxq/1/

HTML:

```
<button id="roll">Go</button>
<div id="screen">
    <div id="rolled" class="vert">12</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.vert {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#screen {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
#rolled {
    font-size: 150px;
    text-align: center; 
    color:#ccc;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

SCRIPT:

```
$("#roll").click(function(){
    // display rolled
    $("#screen").css("display", "block");
        // animate rolled
    var poscss = "{'fontSize' : '0px'};";
    $("#rolled").animate(       
        poscss, 
        "slow",
        "swing",
        function() {
            $("#screen").css("display", "none");
        }
    );  
});
```

It seems to be calling the animate function fine, but nothing occurs. Any tips?
Thanks
Corin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a string while it should be a plain object:

***.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )***

> properties Type: PlainObject An object of CSS properties and values
>   that the animation will move toward.

```
var poscss = {'font-size' : 0}; // 0 instead of '0px' which doesn't make sense, 0 is always 0, unregarding unit
```

### -DEMO-